# Is there a way to compare two dataframes and report which column is different in Pyspark?

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm using `df1.subtract(df2).rdd.isEmpty()` to compare two dataframes (assuming the schema of these two df are the same, or at least we expect them to be the same), but if one of the column doesn't match, I can't tell from the output logs, and it takes long time for me to find out the issue in the data (and it's exhausting when the datasets are quite big)

Is there a way that we can compare two df and return which column doesn't match with Pyspark? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you add an example to your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [chispa library](https://github.com/MrPowers/chispa), it is a great tool for comparing data frames.